# Running a bash command in the middle of a Curl command

Tags: bash, unix, curl

I'm trying to run a curl command that puts the value of the date from my bash shell in the string but it doesn't work:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{
  \"version\": date +%s
}" "https://api.example.com/"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date +%s` is considered as a regular string in your current command.
Use command substitution to get the needed timestamp value:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-d '{"version":'$(date +%s)'}'
```